# Find the largest exponent x such that p^x evenly divides n

Tags: java

> Write a method `getExponent(n, p)` that returns the largest exponent
>   *x* such that *p*<sup>*x*</sup> evenly divides *n*. If *p* ≤ 1 the method should return -1.
>
> - `getExponent(162, 3)` returns 4 because 162 = 2<sup>1</sup>∙ 3<sup>4</sup>, therefore the value of `x` here is 4.
> - if `n` is 27 and `p` is 3, return 3 because 3<sup>3</sup> divides 27 evenly but 3<sup>4</sup> does not.
> - if `n` is 28 and `p` is 3, return 0 because 3<sup>0</sup> divides 28 evenly but 3<sup>1</sup> does not.
> - if `n` is 280 and `p` is 7, return 1 because 7<sup>1</sup> divides 280 evenly but 7<sup>2</sup> does not.
> - if `n` is -250 and `p` is 5, return 3 because 5<sup>3</sup> divides -250 evenly but 5<sup>4</sup> does not.`
> - if `n` is 18 and `p` is 1, return -1 because if `p <= 1` the function returns -1.
> - if `n` is 128 and `p` is 4, return 3 because 4<sup>3</sup> divides 128 evenly but 4<sup>4</sup> does not.

I wrote following code to test that result

```
public class Exponent {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 27;
    int p = 3;
    System.out.println("result is: " + getExponent(n, p));
}

public static int getExponent(int n, int p) {
    int count = 0;
    if (p <= 1) {
        count = -1;
    } else {
        boolean status = true;
        while (status) {
            if (n % p == 0) {
                count++;
                n = n / p;
            } else {
                status = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
}
```

I checked whether `n` is divisible by `p` or not. If divisible, then increment `count` and return `count`. Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: There are some more efficient ways to solve this problem. A slight clue, if p^x | n, we can check if p^2x | n. If it does, we need not test x, x + 1, .. 2x -1, 2x. If it doesn't, we can check if p^floor(1.5x) | n.  (Binary search)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm is right, but the flow control is clumsy:

- The special case of *p* ≤ 1 should trigger an immediate `return`.
- Flag variables suck.  Don't set a variable that tells the program where to go, when you could just use the right keywords and loop conditions to go there.

Instead of `count`, I suggest using `x`, sticking to the terminology in the problem statement.

```
public static int getExponent(int n, int p) {
    if (p <= 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    int x = 0;
    for (; n % p == 0; n /= p) {
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Note that there is an implicit `Exponent` constructor.  I suggest suppressing it by defining

```
private Exponent() {}
```

Comment: ok, it seems more prefect in case of flow control and define variable.

Answer (score 6):

I would do an "early exit" in the case \$ p \le 1 \$ and 
save an indentation level for the "main case":

```
if (p <= 1) {
    return -1;
}
```

The `status` variable is not needed, the while-loop can be
simplified to

```
int count = 0;
while (n % p == 0) {
    count++;
    n = n / p;
}
```

Your program should check if the input number \$ n \$
is zero, otherwise it will run into an infinite loop in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the excellent answer by 200_success, I felt like posting my own answer, as this question reminded me of my own college days, Data Structures class.

Here's what I'd write as an answer:

```
// Problem: find the largest exponent x such that p^x evenly divides n
import java.util.Scanner;

class LargestExponent {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        LargestExponent le = new LargestExponent();
        le.callMethod();
    }

    private void callMethod() {
        int n, p;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter value of p: ");
        p = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value of x is: " + this.getExponent(n, p));

    }

    private int getExponent(int number, int div) {
        int x = 0;
        if(div <= 1) return -1;
         while(number%div == 0) {
            x++;
            number = number/div;
        }
        return x;
    }

}
```

- Our professor always insisted on using a single return statement; I never really found out why. I guess he thought students will make excessive use of `return`. Here, however, we have to write one less `else` if there's a return, so why not? It reduces code clutter. In the class, this'd have gotten me a 3/5.
- Instead of hardcoded values, I have used a `Scanner` class. It's typically C-ish, but it ensures there are no hard-coded 'magic numbers'. And it makes it easy to carry out all those tests in the question without having to edit the code.
- The professor also discouraged the 'break the infinite loop' tendency. Instead he always had us break the loop through the `while()` condition. Better that way.
- I'm also curious why you used:

  int n = 27;
  int p = 3;
  System.out.println("result is: " + getExponent(n, p));

`System.out.println("result is: " + getExponent(27, 3));` would have been better.

Comment: One thing both of us didn't do is to account for the divisibility of 2. Since 2^0 is allowed, its contribution can be ignored. But in other cases you'll have to check divisibility of 2 first: `n%2 == 0`, and divide by 2 before calculating x.

Comment: I don't see why 2 is a special case. Perhaps you are misinterpreting "evenly divides" to mean that the quotient must be **even**? It just means there is no remainder, nothing more.

Comment: first, i initialize n and p,  but later i removed the declaration  and initialization of n and p. Than, I directly passed the value as you mention  `System.out.println("result is: " + getExponent(27, 3));`.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, that's exactly what I interpreted that to be. Also the fact that 162 is denoted as 2^1 * 3^4. I imagined 324, for example, would be represented as 2^2 * 3^4.

Comment: @user3789184 The sole purpose of `n` and `p` here is to be passed to the method. The arguments are passed by **value**, meaning copies are made that are used in the method body. The original `n`and `p` are unchanged from the `getExponent` method. So it just wastes memory to assign values of n and p to a variable. An exception is when you have to declare them as constants similar to C's `#define` where you define them as `const` in the main `public` class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out two shortcomings of the assignment, that lead to bad code:

- `getExponent` is a terrible name. It doesn't describe at all what it does. (However to be honest, I can't think of a better name that wouldn't be far too long).
- It's usually a bad idea to have a function like this return a "valid" value (in the sense it's a valid integer) to indicate an error case, because it will wreck havoc, if the user forgets to catch it. Instead the method should throw an exception, or return `null` or an `Optional`.

And one other small thought: An alternative way to solve this problem (although most likely a slower, but IMO interesting way), would be to get the prime factors for the input arguments, and see how often the factors of `p` can be found in `n`. E.g., for `getExponent(540, 6)`:

$$\begin{align*}
540 &= 2^2 \times 3^3 \times 5 \\
6 &= 2^1 \times 3^1
\end{align*}$$

So both 2 and 3 (the factors of 6) can be found (at least) twice in the factors of 540, so the solution is 2.